# what is scope of $this in php in oop

Tags: php, oop

what is scope of $this in php,can we declare out side function , in class

```
class Blogs extends Controller

{

     public  $articlesmodel = $this->loadmodel('articlesmodel');
     public function index()
     {      
          if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['login_id'])){
            header("location:".URL);
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: `$this` can only be used inside class methods.

Comment: And property declarations can only take constant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Blogs` class it would be on the class boundaries.
But you are `extending` `Controller` class also. So with `$this` you can access all the `public` & `protected` members of `Controller` class.

In the above code - `$this->loadmodel('articlesmodel');` is accessing the method of `Controller` class(if `Controller` class is not extending any other class that contains the method).

**Update**

You cannot have expressions or function calls in the variable declarations.For the error do -

```
class Blogs extends Controller

{
     public $articlesmodel;
     function __construct()
     {
        $this->articlesmodel = $this->loadmodel('articlesmodel');
     }
     public function index()
     {      
          if(!isset($_SESSION['user']['login_id'])){
            header("location:".URL);
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: so  public  $articlesmodel = $this->loadmodel('articlesmodel'); is not correct

Comment: Why not??it makes `$articlesmodel` public member in `Blogs` class.

Comment: but i am getting error ,Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\wamp\www\www\demo\application\controller\Blogs.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

`$this` represents the instance of the class itself, so you can access anything and everything in that class, including private variables, functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use $this to refer to the current object. Use self to refer to the current class. In other words, use  $this->member for non-static members, use self::$member for static members.

$this = current class